Computing flux integral in two ways what is my mistake?

So doing it this way is easy $ \int_D \nabla F dV $ which gives me $8/3$
But doing it via $ \int _{\delta D}F\cdot nds=\int _{\delta D}F\cdot n\left|r\left(t\right)\right|dt$ gives me troubles.
After drawing a diagram and getting my normal vectors $\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}-2t\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ and respective paths $r_1\left(t\right)=\begin{pmatrix}t\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $r_2\left(t\right)=\begin{pmatrix}t\\ t^2\end{pmatrix}$
The first integral becomes $$\int _{-1}^1\begin{pmatrix}t\\ t\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\sqrt{1^2+0}dt$$ which gives me $2$. Simiarly, the second integral gives me $-4/3$ and adding them together gives me $2/3$ which contradicts $8/3$ !!!
Edit: this is the method i want to use


Have you verified that your normal vectors are both: pointing in the correct directions for divergence theorem? unit vectors? Separately from those two issues, your parametrization inside of the first line integral you did was wrong.

sorry it should be (0, t) you are right, a line at y = 1  and x = 0
. Yes the normal vectors are normal pointing away fromt eh curves and unit vectors. (in the second path the unit scaler cancels out with the ds = |...|dt

after differentiation the $(0,t)$ becomes $(0, 1)$ and then the normal vector is $(-1, 0)$

It's good you checked these things. However you're still incorrect about how the second normal vector points. Hint: on the right side of the parabola, do you want the vector pointing right or left? Or even at the vertex, do you want the vector pointing up or down?

For your second comment, I'm confused what you're talking about. What is $(0,t)$, and why must it be differentiated?

$(0, t)$ is $r(t)$ so we want $r'(t)$. At the right of the parabola i want the vector to point right. Ok so actually it should be $(2t, -1)$ ie. the minus is on the bottom entry. Then my integration is just $4/3$ which is just the opposite sign of what i have computed. Adding this to $2$ still doesnt give me $8/3$

The integral you are supposed to calculate does not involve $|r'(t)|,.$ It looks like you are mixing up line integrals of vector fields with those of scalar fields.

@KurtG.i belieev it should, please look at the edit i have made

By Gauss' theorem in 2D
you are supposed to calculate
$$\tag1
\int_{\partial D}F_y\,dx-F_x\,dy=
\int_{\partial D}y\,dx-x\,dy\,.
$$
When a part of the boundary of $D$ is parametrized by
$$
[a,b]\ni t\mapsto \pmatrix{x(t)\\y(t)}
$$
then the integral over that part is
$$
\int_a^b\Big\{y(t)\,\frac{dx(t)}{dt}-x(t)\,\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\Big\}\,dt=
\int_a^b\Big\{y(t)\,\dot x(t)-x(t)\,\dot y(t)\Big\}\,dt\,.
$$
This follows almost automatically from (1). If you realize that
$$
\pmatrix{\dot x\\\dot y}
$$
is the tangent vector to the boundary and
$$
\pmatrix{-\dot y\\\dot x}
$$
the normal vector it should be clear that the integral (1) calculates the flux of $F$ through the boundary.
In your case,
the boundary of $D$ consists of two parts which we parametrize as
$$
[-1,1]\ni t\mapsto\pmatrix{t\\t^2}\,,\quad [-1,1]\ni t\mapsto \pmatrix{\color{red}-t\\1}\,.
$$
The minus sign is necessary for the second part to maintain counterclockwise
orientation.
Then the integral for the first part is
$$
\int_{-1}^1\big\{t^2-2t^2\big\}\,dt=-\frac 23\,.
$$
The integral for the second part is
$$
\int_{-1}^1\big\{-1+t\cdot 0\big\}\,dt=-2\,.
$$
The sum is $-8/3\,.$
Edit: I get now what the mistakes were that you made.

You did not maintain the same orientation on the two parts of $\partial D$ because the signs of your integrals flip: They are $2$ and $-4/3\,.$

Unfortunately you do not show you got $-4/3$ but I am pretty sure that
you forgot to normalize your vector $\mathbf{n}$ to unit length. In my notation you should have done the (obviously unnecessary) calculation
$$
\int_a^b\frac{y(t)\,\dot x(t)-x(t)\,\dot y(t)}{|\dot r(t)|}|\dot r(t)|\,dt 
$$
where
$$
|\dot r(t)|=\sqrt{\dot x^2(t)+\dot y^2(t)}\,.
$$
This integral is (in yet another notation)
$$
\int_C\pmatrix{x\\y}\cdot\boldsymbol{n}\,ds\,.
$$
In your case the unnormalized normal vector on that curved part
of $\partial D$ is $(-2t,t)\,.$

Why that normalization is unnecessary and when it is helpful
in some symmetric situations is explained here.



thanks very much for this approahc, i like it. However, I was mainly interested in this 2nd method (see edit). Since it parallels the way to solve 3D flux integrals.

thank you kurt g, now i undersgtand my mistakes as well. However, i believe the normalising is unecessary and i will provide and edit to my post showing my working out for this case and let you know later.
